# NIntegrate can't integrate function but work fine with the expression

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I have a function called psi0 that looks like this: `psi0 := E^(-(x - 10)^2/10)` and I'm trying to integrate it numerically from 0 to a variable L. However, I keep getting and error saying

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand e^(-(1/10) (-10+x)^2) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,10.}}.
```

I'm using NIntegrate like this: `NIntegrate[psi0[x], {x, 0, L}]` when I get this error but if I do this: `NIntegrate[E^(-(x - 10)^2/10), {x, 0, L}` it works perfectly fine. What's going wrong with the function?

Comment: You write `psi0 :=` then call it using `psi0[x]` ?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to mathematica, how would I fix this?

Comment: Please see below.

Comment: `e` is not defined as a ``System` `` symbol, but `E` is, representing the exact value of the base of the natural logarithm. The letter `e` appears in the warning message, but the letter `E` appears in the code that works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

You had this

```
L = 10;
psi0 := E^(-(x - 10)^2/10)
NIntegrate[psi0[x], {x, 0, L}]
```

[image]

You can't call `psi0[x]` when the function is defined as `psi0:= E^(-(x - 10)^2/10)` . You need to define the function as actually taking an argument `x` for Mathematica to find it and use it.

I set `L=10` since you did not show what `L` was.

Try the following

```
Clear["Global`*"]
L = 10;
psi0[x_] := E^(-(x - 10)^2/10)
NIntegrate[psi0[x], {x, 0, L}]

(*2.80247*)
```

Btw, you do not numerical integrate on this, Mathematica can solve it analytically

```
Clear["Global`*"]
psi0[x_] := E^(-(x - 10)^2/10)
sol = Integrate[psi0[x], {x, 0, L}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol /. L -> 10
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
N[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What does `Clear["Global`*"]` do?

Comment: @AnikPatel it just clears all your variables and other definitions from the notebook so they do not mess up anything in the following calculation.

Comment: How can I make the integral a function? Like if have a function f(n,x) and I want g(n) to be the integral of f(n,x)dx from 0 to L?

Comment: @AnikPatel if I understand you write, may be like this? ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv8w9.png)

Comment: I got it, I wasn't clearing the function and it was screwing me up

Comment: @AnikPatel yes, always clear everything before. That helps.

Comment: @AnikPatel Note that the error message you posted in the question does not conform to the code. Either you defined `psi0[x_] :=...` when you called `NIntegrate[psi0[x], {x, 0, L}]`, or you defined `psi0 :=...` and called `NIntegrate[psi0, {x, 0, L}]`. Defining `psi0 :=...` and calling `NIntegrate[psi0[x], {x, 0, L}]` would produce an error message with `(E^(-(1/10) (-10+x)^2))[x]` for the evaluated expression, not `e^(-(1/10) (-10+x)^2))` as shown (note lower case `e`, no `[x]`). Possibly you made a mistake in copying your code or editing the question.

Comment: @AnikPatel I'll offer some conflicting advice. I used to use ``Clear["Global`*"]`` and frequently regretted it. For the last 25 years, I've avoided it. Sometimes I copy-paste-execute code that contains it, and I get so mad I don't even go back to the Q&A. Instead, I use `ClearAll[phi0]` every time I define a function `phi0`. I used to like the ``"Global`*"`` because I wouldn't have to type out every function name, or change the `ClearAll` when I change the function name. But that inconvenience is good programming practice and is nothing compared to the grief of ``Clear["Global`*"]``